# Mapping one to one relationships in Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am trying to map a User with a certain Table in a one to one relationship.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.mile.restoraunt.web.app.entity.CTable.currentUser, referenced property unknown: com.mile.restoraunt.web.app.entity.User.table
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:765) [spring-boot-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:445) [spring-boot-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) [spring-boot-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) [spring-boot-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) [spring-boot-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at com.mile.restoraunt.web.app.MileRestorauntWebAppApplication.main(MileRestorauntWebAppApplication.java:19) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_311]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_311]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_311]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_311]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.mile.restoraunt.web.app.entity.CTable.currentUser, referenced property unknown: com.mile.restoraunt.web.app.entity.User.table
    at org.hibernate.cfg.OneToOneSecondPass.doSecondPass(OneToOneSecondPass.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1693) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1661) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:295) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

This here is my code, id appreciate if u take a look at it:

`User` class:

```java
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Long number;
    private int balance;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Role> roles;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "table_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private CTable currenTable;
    
}
```

The `Table` class:

```java
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Table(name = "table")
public class CTable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    private Boolean available;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "table")
    private User currentUser;
    private Date currentDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mapped parent entity with child entity properly.In parent table object of `CTable` is `currenTable` and you mapped by with `table`.

Change:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "table")
```

To:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "currenTable")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change in the `CTable`  class this line

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "table")
private User currentUser;
```

to

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "currenTable")
private User currentUser;
```

`mappedBy` takes in the name of a Java field as the input parameter.